# How to add more function to the checkbox which has its own current function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

The current function of the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" onfocus="EnsureSelectionHandlerOnFocus(event,this,12)" onclick="ToggleAllItems(event,this,12)" title="Select or deselect all items" id="cbSelectAll" class="s4-selectAllCbx">
```

How can I add more function to the checkbox's onclick like:
`onclick="ToggleAllItems(event,this,12)"` vs `onclick="select_remainingitems();"`

Because of the complexity of the current function of the checkbox, I would like to see that when it is clicked, the checkbox can run both features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
onclick="select_remainingitems();function_two();function_tree();"
```

If you wonder whether you can run two different JS function simultaneously: you can't because Javascript is single threaded.

**EDIT**

I'd suggest this

```
<input type="checkbox" onfocus="EnsureSelectionHandlerOnFocus(event,this,12)" onclick="multiple_functions();" title="Select or deselect all items" id="cbSelectAll" class="s4-selectAllCbx">

function multiple_functions(){
    first_function();
    second_function();
}

function first_function(){
    alert("Im the first function");
}

function second_function(){
    alert("Im the second function");
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It looks nice. Let me try. Thank you.

Comment: How can I add these functions to this one? `document.getElementById("cbSelectAll").onclick = function() { // 2 function go here }`

Answer (score 2):

You Can Try This

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ddfd" /> click me
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click','#ddfd','',function(){
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
});
function function1(){
    alert("function 1");
}

function function2(){
    alert("function 2");
}

function function3(){
    alert("function 3");
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mTBX5/)**

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me a lots with Demo :-).